# I need to understand the proof of theorem $7.8$, in the book of Matsumura,

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In the book of Matsumura, I need to understand the proof of theorem $7.8$, in page $51$.

In the proof $(3) \Rightarrow (1)$, it says the short exact sequence $0 \to I \to A \to A/I \to 0$ induces a long exact sequence $$ 0=\text{Tor}_1^A(M,A/I) \to I \otimes M \to \color{blue}{M} \to M \otimes A/I \to 0,$$ and hence $I \otimes M \to M$ is injective.

In the long exact sequence, why not the blue color $M$ is $A \otimes M$ indeed ? It seems to me that the author has taken tensor product with $M$, and so in place of blue color $M$, it should be $A \otimes M$. Please explain where my thinking is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that Matsumura has identified $M$ with $M\otimes_A A$. This is not a problem, but you should remember the definition of the isomorphism: it is by $m\otimes_A a\mapsto am$.

Comment: Woh! nice. I did not think it. Thank you for your answer

Comment: If $M$ is identified $M \otimes_A A$ by $m \otimes_A a \mapsto am$. Then why not we identify $M$ with $M \otimes_A I$ by $m \otimes_A a \mapsto am$ for all $a \in I \subset A$ ?

Comment: The map that you define will identify $M\otimes_A I$ with $IM$. Of course, it is reasonable to ask why this was not done, but it was probably just a preference on the part of the author.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help

Comment: In order to use $m\otimes_A a\mapsto am$ as an identification, one needs to know that it's an isomorphism. It is an isomorphism in the case of $A$ but not in the case of $I$.

Comment: Ah indeed. I was wrong about that above. I'll leave it there so the correction can be read.